# Environment Variable: PATH

Tags: linux, path

Change the PATH variable in such way the command `ls` should not work.

Restore the PATH variables content. Check whether `ls` is working or not.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about us doing your homework

Comment: ok.. i displayed the content of PATH variable. but i'm not getting how to change its content such that ls wont work??

Comment: @SahajBaranwal What is the question? Some sentence with question mark at the end would be helpful. **Update the question** and use something more specific than "How do I do this?"

Answer (score 4):

I won't say exactly how to do it, because this is obviously homework and the point is that you should learn by yourself and not just copy off of answers here.

But I will give you some hints on how to figure it out.

1. First, you need to find out which directory `ls` lives in. If you don't know how to do that, search the web. A good search term might be "how do I find the path for a unix program".
2. You've already figured out how to see the current content of your PATH variable. Now, you need to change it so that it no longer contains the directory where `ls` lives. A good search term might be "how do I change an environment variable in bash"
3. When you've done that, and you type `ls`, the computer should respond with something along the lines of `ls: command not found`.
4. Now you know how to change your PATH - so you change it again, so that it this time contains the path to `ls`that you found in step 2. Then, the next time you type `ls`, it will show you the contents of the directory you're in.

I hope this sets you on the way. If you run into problems, you can edit this question so that it contains the following information:

- what you did
- what you expected to happen
- what happened instead.

Good luck.